# put div on different line

Tags: html, css

I want to build a list of itens. Each item should be in one line, like several paragraphs.

Why my div.empresa elements are on same line? I think they should be on different lines because the display property of them is block.

Take a look at code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yz8Cq/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to remove `float: left;`

```
#ListaDeEmpresas .arrow {
    height: 50px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url("/Content/SetaBrancoh40.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-color: #A9462F;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/Yz8Cq/5/

Floats can be a bit tricky to get your head around at first. This article is excellent - http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Have a read of the CSS-Tricks article. Floats are explained there - http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: You removed float left only from the .arrow and keep in .label. Why this?

Comment: I already achieved my result putting overflow: hidden on .empresa and keeping float left. What's better solution?

Comment: Assuming you want the arrow next to the label still you want the label to float left. This will put the arrow next to it. The float: left on the arrow as well was putting the next content to the left. does that make sense? Overflow hidden would work, as would clearing the floats.

Comment: Ok thank you. How can I make the arrow take a fixed width and the label get all available space on the line? I also want a 10px space between arrow and label.

Comment: the fixed width is just for arrow. and a fixed width between arrow and label. the label should take all available space.

Comment: I've achieved what I want putting overflow: hidden in label, removing width from label and removing inline-block from label and arrow. take a look http://jsfiddle.net/Yz8Cq/16/

Comment: But how do we move the element to the left then?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, removing `float: left` from the `label` will make the arrow `span` appear to the left of the `label`. Assuming you want the arrow `span`s to continue to show up on the right of the `label`s, then you want to add:

```
#ListaDeEmpresas div.empresa {
    clear: left;
}
```

This will make sure each label/span set appears below the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `float: left;` in `#ListaDeEmpresas .arrow`

Answer (score 2):

The `float: left;` is making them do that.